# Vsnprintf crash for NULL on my embedded target

Tags: c, printf, undefined-behavior

I am trying to use vsnprintf for formatting the log data on embedded board(Its arm based board).

below is the code for my log print

```
#define Max_log_len 1024
char logBuf[Max_log_len+1] = { 0 };

printMessage(const char* Format,...)
{
    va_list logList;
    va_start(logList,  Format);
    vsnprintf(logBuf ,  Max_log_len,Format, logList);
    va_end(logList);
    sendMessageto(logBuf);
}
```

if my data is NULL for string formatting, my program crashes at vsnprintf
below is sample for case.

```
char *dData = NULL;

printMessage("The Obtained data is [%s]",dData);
```

where as on linux(my PC) this properly prints "The Obtained data is null" but on my device it crashes.

any help is appreciated

Comment: So if you pass a null pointer to a function claiming it is a pointer to the initial element of a string, it dereferences null and crashes? How is that in any way unexpected? Just because the C library on your desktop machine has some extra cleverness (over and above the C standard) which protects you from your bad code in that case doesn't make it any less bad.

Comment: _"on linux(my PC) this properly prints ..."_ Everything I find suggests that it's undefined behaviour to call `printf` with `%s` and `NULL` as the corresponding string pointer. I would guess that the same is true for `vsnprintf`.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Since it was working on my linux . I was thinking that cross compiled gcc library has some problem, so shared here to get the inputs .. Now understood that its a expected behaviour for NULL .. Now is there any way to check the NULL string  at argument list(because API user may send the NULL string . so I want to check the NULL stings and add 'null'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C standard from 1999 says:

> 7.1.4 Use of library functions
>
> 1 Each of the following statements applies unless explicitly stated
>   otherwise in the detailed descriptions that follow: If an argument to
>   a function has an invalid value (such as a value outside the domain of
>   the function, or a pointer outside the address space of the program,
>   or a null pointer,or a pointer to non-modifiable storage when the
>   corresponding parameter is not const-qualified) or a type (after
>   promotion) not expected by a function with variable number of
>   arguments, the behavior is undefined.

This is the case. There's no surprise that the embedded C library chooses not to detect all possible error cases in order to save memory.

Comment: is there any way to check the NULL string at argument list(because API user may send the NULL string . so I want to check the NULL stings and add 'null'

Comment: @puttaks Well, you could parse the format string and iterate over va_list yourself, duplicating the inner workings of the various printf's.